# Pass selected value to vuejs function

Tags: vue.js

How can I pass selected value to a vuejs function?
`v-model` won't help I guess.

I need to set values for the filter after
`item: items | orderBy sortKey reverse`
where `reverse` and `sortKey` are dynamic values.

**html**

```
<select class="sort-filter" v-on="change: sortBy(???)">
  <option value="title asc">Title (A-Z)</option>
  <option value="title desc">Title (Z-A)</option>
  <option value="price asc">Price (Min. - Max.)</option>
  <option value="price desc">Price (Max. - Min.)</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (sortKey) {
      console.log(sortKey)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have several ways to do it.

**Edit: Improved 2)**

It is possible to use v-model just like in **2)** but instead of using the value directly in your orderBy filter, you can use [computed properties](http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html)

```
computed: {
    sortKey: {
        get: function() {
            return this.sorting.split(' ')[0]; // return the key part
        }
    },
    sortOrder: {
        get: function() {
            return this.sorting.split(' ')[1]; // return the order part
        }
    }
}
```

This way, sortKey and sortOrder will be available like a normal property in you filter:

```
v-repeat="items | orderBy sortKey sortOrder"
```

**1) Use javascript event:**

If you don't specify any parameter, the native event object will be passed automatically

```
<select class="sort-filter" v-on:change="sortBy">
```

You can then use it like this:

```
methods: {
    sortBy: function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
    },
}
```

**2) Using v-model**

You can add the v-model directive

```
<select name="test" v-model="sorting" v-on:change="sortBy">
```

This way the `sorting` value will be updated on every change.

You can add this value in the data object of you ViewModel to be more clear:

```
data: {
  sorting: null // Will be updated when the select value change
}
```

You can then access the value like in your method:

```
methods: {
    sortBy: function() {
        console.log(this.sorting);
    },
}
```

If you just need to update the `sortKey` value, this method is not even necessary.

**3) Other weird way**

You can apparently use your model value as a parameter.

```
<select name="test" v-model="sortKey" v-on:change="sortBy(sortKey)">
```

This is working but I don't really see the point.

```
methods: {
    sortBy: function(sortKey) {
        console.log(sortKey);
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it tomorrow at the office. The reason I am not using v-model is because the value contains the sort direction as well, like asc or desc. If  I use `v-model` vue will try to sort the results base on for example `title asc` attribute that doesn't exists, so I want to send the selected value to a function, split it and use title as sort attribute and asc or desc as direction. I hope it makes sense what I am saying. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, i think I understand, I'll edit my answer and add a other possible solution.

Comment: One thing to add, `sortOrder` should be a boolean type, true/false, so I had to check if sortOrder equal asc:

`return this.sorting.split(' ')[1] === 'asc' ? false : true`

it won't accept other values than boolean for 3d parameter in the filter.
Thank you.

Comment: #2 worked great for me, butI had to use v-on:change="sortBy" instead

Comment: @user3089840 I edit my answer to use the current event syntax. (a bit late maybe :) )

Answer (score 6):

This should work if you want to loop with dynamic values and can not use v-model

```
<select name="option" v-on:change="selectedOption($event.target.value)">
    <option value="0">SELECT</option>
    <option v-for="i in 10" :value="i">{{ i }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. A way to pass not the entire event (as Vue does by default) but just the value. That way I can share the handler function with elsewhere in the code that doesn't have an event.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass selected value to a vuejs function, Please do the following :

1. you need to use v-model directive in select tag as v-model = variableName
2. pass that variable as parameter like @on-change=sortBy(variableName);

So your code will look like :

```
<select class="sort-filter" v-model="sortingVariable" @on-change="sortBy(sortingVariable)"> 
   <option value="title asc">Title (A-Z)</option>
   <option value="title desc">Title (Z-A)</option>
   <option value="price asc">Price (Min. - Max.)</option>
   <option value="price desc">Price (Max. - Min.)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<select name="option" @change="myFunction($event.target.value)">
   <option v-for="item in list" :value="item.code" :key="item.code">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>

// Function
myFunction(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```