# How to get selected item of b-form-select with Vue.js. v-on:change does nothing?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, select, vuejs2

I just want to get the selected item of the `<b-form-select>` which I want to use for an api call. It looks like v-on:change does nothing, but it was the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31273611/8743351

When I use `console.log(this.selected);` I expect the selected value, but instead I get **undefined**.

There are so many different ways to solve this but nothing worked for me.

```html
<!-- Export -->
<b-navbar toggleable type="light" variant="light">
  <b-nav is-nav-bar>
    <b-nav-item>
      <b-form-select v-model="selected" v-on:change="getSelectedItem" style="width:auto">
        <template slot="first">
              <option :value="null" disabled>-- Select project --</option>
            </template>
        <option v-for="project in projects" v-bind:value="project.value">
          {{ project.id }} {{ project.title }}
        </option>
      </b-form-select>
    </b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>

  <b-nav is-nav-bar>
    <b-nav-item>
      <b-button v-on:click="exportXML();">Export as XML</b-button>
    </b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>
</b-navbar>
```

```js
methods: {
  getSelectedItem: function() {
    console.log(this.selected);
  },
  exportXML: function() {
    console.log(this.selected);
    this.$http.get(
      'http://localhost:8080/api/exports/' + this.selected,
    });
}
}
```

Comment: This should be working can you post the rest of your component script?

Answer (score 10):

**If only interested in the event argument:**

In .html

```
<b-form-select 
    v-model="someobject.state"   <!--This is only used to bind the UI to data for display. In this case the state of the object. It can be anything in the VUE app's context, aka data:{}-->
    v-on:change="getSelectedItem" <!--will call the func getSelectedItem with 1 argument, the value of the newly selected item.-->
/>
```

In .js:

```
....
methods: {
      getSelectedItem: function(myarg) { // Just a regular js function that takes 1 arg
        console.log(myarg);
      },
....
```

**If want to pass multiple arguments including the Event argument:**

In .html

```
<b-form-select 
    v-model="someobject.state"  <!--This is only used to bind the UI to data for display. In this case the state of the object. It can be anything in the VUE app's context, aka data:{}-->
    v-on:change="getSelectedItem($event, someobject.id)" <!--will call the func getSelectedItem with 2 arguments, the value of the newly selected item, and the id of a previously defined object.-->
/>
```

In .js:

```
....
methods: {
      getSelectedItem: function(newObjectState, objectId) { // Just a regular js function that takes 2 args
        console.log(newObjectState + " --- " + objectId);
        updateObjectState(objectId, newObjectState)

      },
....
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles across this, I believe the problem is that the v-on:change is grabbing the value too soon before its been updated. So the result is undefined. If you were to click on another option, you should see that the old value from previous click becomes visible.

I just solved a similar problem. I included the use of debounce to wait to execute the on change method.

That is what is implemented here
https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/5xb9tj/input_call_a_method_but_with_debounce/

You'll also need to npm install loadash and include "import _ from 'lodash'" in the  portion.

Comment: Same problem, is there a way to pass the current selected value with the onChange method and NOT use the global data variable?

Comment: Hey @KasparTr, I think it would be possible by using a watcher. It's useful for performing async tasks. 

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Answer (score 0):

> 

This should be working can you post the rest of your component script? – thanksd

Actually this is all what I got and what has to do with this select form.

```js
  export default {
    userMe: [],
    data() {
      return {
        selected: null,
        options: [],
      }
    },
    created: function() {

    },
    methods: {
      getSelectedItem: function() {
        console.log(this.selected);
      },
      exportXML: function() {
        console.log(this.selected);
        this.$http.get(
          'http://localhost:8080/api/exports/' + this.selected, )
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late, but I modified the function a bit like so and it works, the rest is the same:

```
methods: {
  getSelectedItem: function(selected) {
    console.log(selected);
  },
  exportXML: function(selected) {
    console.log(selected);
    this.$http.get(
      'http://localhost:8080/api/exports/' + selected,
    });
  }
}
```

Note that I am **not grabbing the value from the model**, instead **the selected item is passed to the function**.